# Strange exception thrown: getting the height of a sprites image in SFML

Tags: c++, exception, sfml

Hey so i've tracked down an exception's root which is at this line of code:

```
>= obj2->GetPosition().y + (obj2->GetCenter().y - obj2->GetImage()->GetHeight()))
```

but i have no clue to whats causing it..... the strange part is in the function, which takes two sprite pointers, the function GetImage()->GetHeight() works for object 1, but not a second time for object 2...

**Please Help! I have NO idea why this would be happening! Thanks**

all the code: (search for the line of code i posted earlier)

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<SFML/System.hpp>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#    define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846 
enum{xXx= 0, yYy= 1};
enum{ScreenWidth=800, ScreenHeight=600};

sf::RenderWindow Window;

template<typename T/*, typename T2*/>
bool CheckCollision(T* obj1, T* obj2){ 
    bool xColl=false,yColl=false;
    // check if any part of object 1 is between object 2's top and bottom 
    if(obj1->GetPosition().y + (obj1->GetCenter().y - obj1->GetImage()->GetHeight())
    <= obj2->GetPosition().y + (obj2->GetImage()->GetHeight() - obj2->GetCenter().y)

    && obj1->GetPosition().y + (obj1->GetImage()->GetHeight() - obj1->GetCenter().y)
    >= obj2->GetPosition().y + (obj2->GetCenter().y - obj2->GetImage()->GetHeight()))
        yColl= true;
    // check if any part of object 1 is between object 2's left and right
    if(obj1->GetPosition().x + (obj1->GetCenter().x - obj1->GetImage()->GetWidth())
    <= obj2->GetPosition().x + (obj2->GetImage()->GetWidth() - obj2->GetCenter().x)

    && obj1->GetPosition().x + (obj1->GetImage()->GetWidth() - obj1->GetCenter().x)
    >= obj2->GetPosition().x + (obj2->GetCenter().x - obj2->GetImage()->GetWidth()))
        xColl= true;

    if(xColl==true && yColl==true) return true;
    else return false;
};


template<typename T> 
void CalculateMove(T Time, T Speed, T Angle, T& buffX, T& buffY)
{   //Make the degrees positive
    if(Angle<0) Angle= 360+Angle;

    //determine what quadrant of circle we're in     
    unsigned int   Quadrant= 1;     
    if(Angle>=90)  Quadrant= 2;     
    if(Angle>=180) Quadrant= 3;    
    if(Angle>=270) Quadrant= 4;

    //anything above 90 would be impossible triangle
    Angle= (float)(Angle-(int)Angle)+(float)((int)Angle%90); 

    // calculates x and y based on angle and Hypotenuse
    if((int)Angle!=0){
        if(Quadrant==2 || Quadrant==4) Angle=90-Angle; //The unit circle triangle is flipped otherwise, causing x and y to be switched
        buffY= sin(Angle / 180 * M_PI)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));  
        buffX= sin((180-Angle-90)/ 180 * M_PI)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));}

    else{// Movement is a straight line on X or Y axis
        if(Quadrant==1 || Quadrant==3) buffX= Speed*Time;
        if(Quadrant==2 || Quadrant==4) buffY= Speed*Time;}

    //Quadrant Factor (positive or negative movement on the axis)
    switch(Quadrant){
    case 1: break;
    case 2: buffX=-buffX; break;
    case 3: buffX=-buffX; buffY=-buffY; break;
    case 4: buffY=-buffY; break;}
};

template<typename T>
struct MoveData{
    float X,Y;
    T* Object;
    MoveData(float x, float y, T* object):X(x), Y(y), Object(object){};
};

/////////////////////////////////////////   Mysprite    ////////////////////////////////
class mySprite : public sf::Sprite
{
private:
    float velocity;
    float angle;

public:
    // all the values needed by the base class sprite();
    mySprite(
        const sf::Image& Img, 
        const sf::Vector2f& Position = sf::Vector2f(0, 0), 
        const sf::Vector2f& Scale = sf::Vector2f(1, 1), 
        float Rotation = 0.f, 
        const float Angle= 0.f, 
        const float Velocity= 0.f, 
        const sf::Color& Col = sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255)):
      Sprite(Img, Position, Scale, Rotation, Col){
        angle= Angle;
        velocity= Velocity;};

    float Velocity(){return velocity;};
    void SetVelocity(float newVelocity){velocity=newVelocity;};
    float Angle(){return angle;};
    void SetAngle(float newAngle){angle=(float)(newAngle-(int)newAngle)+(float)((int)newAngle%360);};

    void Update(){ 
        float frameTime= Window.GetFrameTime();
        float X=0,Y=0;
        //SetRotation(angle);
        CalculateMove(frameTime,velocity,angle,X,Y);
        Move(X,-Y);
    };

    void Accelerate(float PPS){velocity+=PPS;};
    void Turn(float degrees){
        angle=(float)((angle+degrees)-(int)(angle+degrees))+(float)((int)(angle+degrees)%360);};

    void Reflect(float CollAngle){
        SetRotation(-GetRotation());
        angle=360-angle;
        //TODO: factor in the collision angle
    };
};

class MoveBuff
{
private:
    std::vector<MoveData<mySprite>> buff;

public:
    void AddMove(mySprite obj, float X, float Y){
        MoveData<mySprite> data(X, Y, &obj);
        buff.push_back(data);};

    void TestColl(){
        for(unsigned int Object= 0; Object< buff.size(); Object++){
            for(unsigned int CollCheck=Object+1; CollCheck<=buff.size()-1; CollCheck++){    
                if(CheckCollision(buff[Object].Object, buff[CollCheck].Object)){
                    buff[Object].Object->Reflect(0);
                    buff[Object].Object->Reflect(0);}}}
    };

    void Move(){
        for(unsigned int I= 0; I<buff.size(); I++)
            buff[I].Object->Move(buff[I].X, buff[I].Y);
    };
};

int main()
{
    Window.Create(sf::VideoMode(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight), "Pong! by Griffin Howlett", sf::Style::Resize | sf::Style::Close);

    sf::Image img;
    img.Create(30,50,sf::Color(255,0,0));
    mySprite box(img, sf::Vector2f(400,0), sf::Vector2f(1,1), 0, 270, 100); //TODO: test collision with different speeds
    box.SetCenter(15,25);

    sf::Image img2;
    img2.Create(56.5,80,sf::Color(255,0,0));
    mySprite box2(img2, sf::Vector2f(400,400), sf::Vector2f(1,1), 0, 90, 100);
    box2.SetCenter(25,40);

    Window.Display();

    for(;;){
        Window.Clear();
        MoveBuff MoveBuff;
        float frameTime= Window.GetFrameTime();
        float X=0,Y=0;

        CalculateMove(frameTime,box.Velocity(),box.Angle(),X,Y);
        MoveBuff.AddMove(box,X,Y);

        CalculateMove(frameTime,box2.Velocity(),box2.Angle(),X,Y);
        MoveBuff.AddMove(box2,X,Y);

        MoveBuff.TestColl();
        MoveBuff.Move();

        Window.Draw(box);
        Window.Draw(box2);
        Window.Display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MoveData(float x, float y, T* object):X(x), Y(y), Object(object){}; // Constructor
                                                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              //  Just making a reference to the argument. Shallow copy.



void AddMove(mySprite obj, float X, float Y){

    MoveData<mySprite> data(X, Y, &obj);
    buff.push_back(data);

}// => lifetime of the obj ends at this point.
```

The constructor is making a shallow copy. In the initializer list, you are just making a reference to the argument. But the life time of `obj` ends after the call to `MoveBuff::AddMove`. So, `MoveData::Object` goes dangling. And dereferencing is what causing you exception. Instead make a deep copy.

```
void TestColl()
{
    for(unsigned int Object= 0; Object< buff.size(); Object++){
        for(unsigned int CollCheck=Object+1; CollCheck<=buff.size()-1; CollCheck++){    
             if(CheckCollision(buff[Object].Object, buff[CollCheck].Object)){
                // ^^^^^^^^^ This the problem. buff[Object].Object is dangling.
```